# Is Nirvana a goal or a process, shaping the pursuit of enlightenment and a meaningful life?

Tags: nirvana

In examining the Buddhist doctrine of 'Nirvana,' a scholarly critique emerges. Does Nirvana, often portrayed as the ultimate goal, withstand rigorous scrutiny? Can it be dissected as a concrete destination, or is it a nebulous concept, resistant to precise definition? This critical inquiry prompts an exploration into the interpretive challenges, potential inconsistencies, and scholarly debates surrounding the elusive notion of Nirvana within Buddhist philosophy.

Comment: Please don't post questions in order to answer them yourself. This policy (against self-answered questions) is unlike the policy on other SE sites. The policy was decided on Meta, e.g. [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2481/254) and [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2500/254). Not many users (in total) voted but a majority of least of the current moderators voted against it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Nirvana a goal or a process, shaping the pursuit of enlightenment and a meaningful life?

Nirvana is a goal. One should work/walk towards it and achieve it.

---

Buddhism's main theme is, **being in the present**. Which gives the **ability** / enough **concentration** to see the **truth**. (see/understand **four noble truths**.)

Buddha only speaks of the past, to let people know how other people walked the **path to Nirvana**.
Budda has only spoken about the future very little because it is less meaningful. (Only normal(us) misguided people think the future is the most important.)

Buddha only encourages us to be in the present, which is the only path to Nirvana.

**How to be at present?**

Buddha teaches how to be in the present all over the **Damma**. (Buddha's teachings.)
It's about concentration. It's about knowing what's going on in you, around you. (Not dreaming about the past and future.)
You can practice **Samatha meditation** to get absolute concentration.
(This is not the true purpose of Buddha's teaching.)

Now, One should use this concentration/ability to be in the present to understand the **Four Noble Truths**(Nirvana).

Which is **vipassana meditation** (The process of using concentration to understand the Four Noble Truths).

Which is the **main goal of Buddhism**.

**Thanks . ☸️.**

*Questions are welcome.*

Answer (score 0):

Like all of the True Dhamma, Nirvana can only be known by direct experience, as the Pali Suttas explain (e.g. [AN 9.47](https://suttacentral.net/an9.47/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)).